# ESP audio kit speech recognition example not working

Tags: c++, c, esp32

I am frustrated with this error that has got me stuck for approx 3 days till now. I am trying to setup esp32 audio framework for the ESP32 audio kit by AI-thinker.

```
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_reset+0x0): undefined reference to `sr_rb_reset'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x18): undefined reference to `sr_rb_read'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x1c): undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_push_by_qmf'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x20): undefined reference to `dl_dilation_layerq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x24): undefined reference to `dl_convq_lstm_layer'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x28): undefined reference to `dl_atrous_conv1dq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x2c): undefined reference to `dl_relu_convq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x30): undefined reference to `dl_convq_to_matrix2dq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o):(.literal.lvcsr_model_run_accelerate+0x34): undefined reference to `dl_matrix2d_from_matrixq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o): in function `model_destroy':
/home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:257: undefined reference to `dl_matrixq_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:258: undefined reference to `dl_matrixq_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:259: undefined reference to `dl_matrixq_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:275: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:274: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:277: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:278: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:282: undefined reference to `sr_rb_unint'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o): in function `model_detect':
/home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:557: undefined reference to `sr_rb_write'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o): in function `model_create':
/home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:339: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:345: undefined reference to `dl_matrixq_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:347: undefined reference to `dl_matrixq_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:347: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:350: undefined reference to `dl_matrixq_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:351: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:352: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:356: undefined reference to `sr_rb_init'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o): in function `add_speech_commands':
/home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:216: undefined reference to `get_id_name'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o): in function `lvcsr_reset':
/home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:395: undefined reference to `sr_rb_reset'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libmultinet.a(multinet1_quantized_cn.o): in function `lvcsr_model_run_accelerate':
/home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:439: undefined reference to `sr_rb_read'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:452: undefined reference to `dl_convq_queue_push_by_qmf'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:456: undefined reference to `dl_dilation_layerq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:461: undefined reference to `dl_dilation_layerq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:466: undefined reference to `dl_dilation_layerq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:471: undefined reference to `dl_dilation_layerq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:483: undefined reference to `dl_convq_lstm_layer'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:487: undefined reference to `dl_atrous_conv1dq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:489: undefined reference to `dl_relu_convq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:492: undefined reference to `dl_atrous_conv1dq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:495: undefined reference to `dl_relu_convq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:498: undefined reference to `dl_atrous_conv1dq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:510: undefined reference to `dl_convq_to_matrix2dq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:510: undefined reference to `dl_matrix2d_from_matrixq'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:511: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:512: undefined reference to `dl_softmax'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:524: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/wangwangwang/workspace/AI/esp_sr_lib/components/multinet/multinet1_quantized_cn.c:524: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.model_destroy+0x0): undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x4): undefined reference to `dl_basic_conv_layer_quantised_weight'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x8): undefined reference to `dl_relu'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0xc): undefined reference to `dl_matrix_slice'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x10): undefined reference to `dl_basic_lstm_layer_quantised_weights'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x14): undefined reference to `dl_matrix_concat'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x18): undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x1c): undefined reference to `dl_fully_connect_layer'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x20): undefined reference to `dl_softmax'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):(.literal.wakeNet4_model_run+0x24): undefined reference to `dl_matrix_zero'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o): in function `model_destroy':
/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:106: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:107: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:108: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:109: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:110: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:111: more undefined references to `dl_matrix_free' follow
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o): in function `wakeNet4_model_run':
/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:239: undefined reference to `dl_basic_conv_layer_quantised_weight'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:240: undefined reference to `dl_relu'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:246: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_slice'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:247: undefined reference to `dl_basic_lstm_layer_quantised_weights'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:249: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_slice'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:250: undefined reference to `dl_basic_lstm_layer_quantised_weights'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:254: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_concat'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:255: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:256: undefined reference to `dl_fully_connect_layer'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:257: undefined reference to `dl_relu'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:260: undefined reference to `dl_fully_connect_layer'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:261: undefined reference to `dl_softmax'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:267: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_zero'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:268: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_zero'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:269: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_zero'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:270: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_zero'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:271: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:272: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_free'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o): in function `model_create':
/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:176: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:180: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:183: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:186: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:188: undefined reference to `dl_matrix_alloc'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(wakenet4_quantized.o):/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/wakenet4_quantized.c:190: more undefined references to `dl_matrix_alloc' follow
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(mfcc_runner_straight.o):(.literal.run_logfbank+0x0): undefined reference to `csf_preemphasis_step'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(mfcc_runner_straight.o):(.literal.run_logfbank+0x4): undefined reference to `csf_logfbank_HTK_step'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(mfcc_runner_straight.o):(.literal.run+0x0): undefined reference to `csf_mfcc_HTK'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(mfcc_runner_straight.o): in function `run_logfbank':
/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/mfcc_runner_straight.c:70: undefined reference to `csf_preemphasis_step'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: /home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/mfcc_runner_straight.c:72: undefined reference to `csf_logfbank_HTK_step'
c:/users/admin/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:/esp/ESP32-A1S-AudioKit/components/esp-sr/lib\libwakenet.a(mfcc_runner_straight.o): in function `run':
/home/sunxiangyu/esp/esp_sr_lib/components/wakenet/mfcc_runner_straight.c:60: undefined reference to `csf_mfcc_HTK'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

I tried using git submodule update --init but the error still persists. Please help me out in this.
I am using esp idf version 4.3 and esp adf version 2 with esptool at 3.1
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe try using a `--recursive` flag too? If you're getting this from a public repo the project should have a readme or some kind of documentation that offers instructions on how to build it. If you've followed them and it's still not working, the authors might be interested to learn about your particular setup so you can both work together to improve the overall protability of project or identify previously unknown limitations.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I have actually used the recursive flag and used exactly the way its specified in the documentation but still not able to get the trick. It had worked flawlessly on my linux computer but when I ported to windows it isn't compiling and now the project is stuck at it.

Comment: You interrogated the usual suspects for undefined references? The linker aspects of your building I mean.

Comment: Do you mean the files mfcc_runner_straight.c ? I tried to find it but its not available...I cant find the files online too